# If "some paper" means "a sheet of paper", then what would be the plural form of "some paper"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, grammaticality-in-context

This is from a native speaker on BBC, [Mr. Maker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-LPTY7CMu0) (see: 2:38-2:44). He says:

**Now how about we get some white paper and draw two fluffy cloud shapes.**

When he says this, he takes a sheet of paper and starts drawing onto it. And I understand that **"..some paper.."** means **"a sheet of paper".**

Then, I wonder what would be the plural form of **"some paper"** if he needed two or three more?

**"..we get two papers.."** would mean something else.

I thought maybe we could say **"...we get two paper..."?,** couldn't we?

Or we could only say "**....we get two sheets of paper..."**, and nothing else would work?

Answer (score 3):

**Some paper means *any* number of sheets of paper**, not specifically one sheet.

So the phrase "get some white paper" is equally good whether you need one sheet, two sheets, five sheets, or fifty.

If you want to be specific, then your final form is correct: **we get one sheet of paper** or **we get two sheets of paper**.